# Rails FactoryGirl instance different from ActiceRecord instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

Howcome when I use FactoryGirl to create a record and later update said record the factorygirl instance isn't updated? For example if I have the following factory and rspec test:

```
factory :foo do
  bar false
end
```

Inside of an rspec test:

```
foo = FactoryGirl.create(:foo)
Foo.first.update_attribute(:bar, true)
expect(foo.bar).to eq(true) #foo.bar is false and will fail
```

If I change `foo.bar` in that last line to `Foo.first.bar` it passes, why the variance? Is the FactoryGirl instance not directly associated to the record? Performing the test `expect(foo).to eq(Foo.first)` returns true so are they not the same object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might have to change

```
expect(foo.bar).to eq(true)
```

to

```
expect(foo.reload.bar).to eq(true)
```

By the way, you might like to know about `be_true`:

```
expect(foo.reload.bar).to be_true
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the reload method. Everything works now. :)